# C# How to redirect stream to the console Out?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I found lots of samples how to redirect console output into a file. However I need an opposite solution - I have StreamWriter which I want to be shown in the Console output once I do `sw.WriteLine("text");`

Comment: I'm a little confused. What is the stream initialized to, if not `Console.Out`? Is it writing both to a file _and_ to the console?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Just point the stream to standard output:

```
sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
sw.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(sw);
```

Answer (score 11):

Not that previous answer not correct, but since i do not have enough reputation level to add comment, just adding another answer:

If you would ever use pointing Stream to standard output as John proposed with using statement you should not forget to re-open console Stream later on, as explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
using (sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput())
{
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(sw);
    ...
}
StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the sample code in the link you provided.. Wont downvote you. I appreciate your effort :)