# Converting StreamWriters to StreamReader

Tags: c#, stream, pipe, streamreader, streamwriter

I was just wondering really if there was an easy way to redirect the output from a StreamReader (in my case one from a NamedPipeClientStream) to the input of a StreamWriter (in my case the one in Console.Out).

Of course you could do this fairly easily with a simple while loop redirecting the data but at the same time I also want to redirect the console's input to a stream writer and out to the Pipe.

I could do it with threads but it seems a bit of a waste of a thread... So I ask, is there a nice way to link streams together?

Been at this all day and I haven't found an easy way yet :/

Comment: may be u can use Console.SetOut http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Already tried, comes back to the same problem of the wrong type of stream :/

Comment: try this ```Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(streamreader.BaseStream));```

Comment: Tried similar, tried your code, still nothing gets through unfortunately

Comment: my last attempt. did u checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127498/c-sharp-how-to-redirect-stream-to-the-console-out

Comment: Still don't think that helps, trouble is I have a stream reader not a stream writer. I know about the Console.SetOut etc,but I haven't got the right input :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From .NET 4.5 on, there is the `Stream.CopyToAsync` method:

[How do I copy the contents of one stream to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copytoasync.aspx

Comment: I'll try it as so as I've sorted out my code :) kinda screwed another bit up :P

Comment: Works for outputting to the console! Need to sort input myself I think :) Thank!