# How to record echo mssage displayed on command prompt using C#?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, c#

I am using below function to call EAR_Encrypt_FTP.bat in C#. Is there any way to trace the echo messages dispayed in cmd.exe while running the batch file??

I need to process echo messages displayed on command prompt screen log the process.

```
private static short batchfileInvoke(string ftpFileName, string headerFile)
{
    short value = 0;
    Process p = null;
    try
    {
        p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        string argument1 = "EAR_Encrypt_FTP.bat";
        string test = "\"" + ftpFileName + "\"";
        string argument2 = test;
        string test1 = "\"" + headerFile + "\"";
        string argument3 = test1;
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(argument1);
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C EAREncryptFTP.bat " + argument2 + " " + argument3;
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        int value2 = p.ExitCode;
        value = (short)value2;
        if(value==0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Encryption process is done");
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred :{0},{1}",
                    ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        value = -4;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Search for `c#` `console` `redirect` may yield [something](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127519/3959875).